# installing npm package.json ansible task

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I want to install package.json using ansible, I'm using the example from the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/npm_module), only thing different from this is that I'm using npm not nvm so the tasks look like this

```
- name: npm install (manual)
  npm:
    path:"{{ project_path }}"
    executable: /usr/bin/npm
```

`{{ project_path }}` is path to `package.json` file, basically it's `/srv/example.com/`.

The result of this tasks is

```
TASK [angular : npm install (manual)] ******************************************
task path: /srv/example.com/orchestration/ansible/roles/angular/tasks/main.yml:16
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/packaging/language/npm.py
<default> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<default> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'
<default> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1540437954.12-74081721294328 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1540437954.12-74081721294328="` echo /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1540437954.12-74081721294328 `" ) && sleep 0'
<default> PUT /tmp/tmpkx6E4h TO /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1540437954.12-74081721294328/npm.py
<default> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1540437954.12-74081721294328/ /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1540437954.12-74081721294328/npm.py && sleep 0'
<default> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-anopitzukaokwawzhqmxqjfzoxjtozxh; /usr/bin/python /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1540437954.12-74081721294328/npm.py; rm -rf "/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1540437954.12-74081721294328/" > /dev/null 2>&1'"'"' && sleep 0'
ok: [default] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "executable": "/usr/bin/npm", 
            "global": false, 
            "ignore_scripts": false, 
            "name": null, 
            "path": "/srv/example.com/", 
            "production": false, 
            "registry": null, 
            "state": "present", 
            "version": null
        }
    }
}
```

It does not do anything, why? How can I install my `package.json`, can someone please help me understand how to overcome this, thanks.

Comment: According to [the source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.5.10/lib/ansible/modules/packaging/language/npm.py#L268), it will do that if all the deps are already installed. Are you certain they aren't already installed, and I would encourage you to check the global `node_modules` since you're running npm as root (not that _this task_ installed them globally, but that they _were already_ installed globally)

Comment: Hey, `npm -g ls --depth=0` will only show `angular/cli` and `npm` installed, so nope it didn't installed `package.json` globally

Comment: It's Ansible version, changed to `2.5.0` from `2.3.2`, and it works, more info [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/33555)